# how to remove systemd from debian Wheezy

Tags: debian, systemd

I have **Debian Wheezy**. by mistake, I have installed systemd. it seems that it was not installed well but now it became default init manager. I can not reboot and can not restart services.

```
apt-get remove systemd
```

[image]

```
dpkg -S /sbin/init tell that
```

`sysvinit: /sbin/init` is default init manager

How can I remove `systemd` or set that `sysvinit` is a default?

Answer (score 2):

I'm doing this from memory (don't have a Wheezy VM anymore), so I'll likely suggest some things that aren't a thing (such as a slightly wrong path). I gots me a good memory, though. Bear with me, please.

First, check your GRUB default config file. It's in /etc/default/grub. Look for the kernel argument "init=" within the GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT line. Make sure it points explicitly to /sbin/init (it certainly shouldn't point to systemd). IF it doesn't exist, put it in, a la: GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="init=/sbin/init" (plus keeping whatever other critical things you might already have in that line).

Rebuild your grub boot file with "grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg" 
!!! Please do check the validity of that command. Wheezy might store the grub in a slightly different place, such as /boot/grub2/grub.cfg, or might use grub-mkconfig rather than grub2-mkconfig. Either way it goes, if the paths are right it's all the same. To be clear, this is to generate your boot menu. If in doubt, back up your boot menu file first so you can backpedal if things get really scatalogical.

Once you've done that, reboot the system so you can stop using systemd and start using sysvinit. This is critical to being able to remove systemd. You'll probably have to issue a hard reset. I don't know what this box does, but you may want to look into freezing the filesystem beforehand and issuing a "sync" command before doing this, since you can't stop any services. But you know more of what these boxen are tasked with than I, obviously.

Next, purge the package for systemd after you presumably boot into sysvinit without horrible issues. "apt-get remove --purge --auto-remove systemd"

Comment: Heh, excellent. Glad to be of help.

Comment: @Tarsem:   Please do not add a comment or an Answer to say "Thank you". - If you want to say "thank you," [vote up](http://serverfault.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that person's answer, or simply pay it forward by providing a great answer to someone else's question. - See [this FAQ page](http://serverfault.com/help/someone-answers) with regards to the etiquette on ServerFault and related sites. - (If this is an Answer to a Question you yourself asked then you additionally have the option to accept it as the correct answer.)